# Google Authorship is not showing on the blog

Tags: google-search-console

I have a blog and it's called "sharing the learning..". I was trying to display Google Authorship on my blog since last 2 months but unfortunately it's not working.

Currently I have this URL of my Google+ Page: `https://plus.google.com/+MananPatel1988/` and the profile name is Manan Patel.

Now I am posting my steps which I have read on the web:

1. I have added this tag in my HTML: `<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MananPatel1988/" />`
2. Current Contributor > Label: `Manan Patel` & URL: `http://www.mananpatel.in`

After this step, I checked [Google Structured Data Testing Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=www.mananpatel.in) but it returned this message:

> "The excerpt from the page will show up here. The reason we can't show text from your webpage is because the text depends on the query the user types."

How can I add the authorship the right way?

Comment: Here is [the official response](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en) from Google: *"Authorship markup is no longer supported in web search."*

Answer (score 2):

Google stopped showing authorship results in search. See http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/08/28/google-stops-showing-authorship-search-results-will-still-include-google-posts-friends-pages/

Answer (score 2):

Google Authorship Support Dropped

https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/HZf3KDP1Dm8

Answer (score 0):

Google has stopped Authorship Since last few days.

You can check [official announcement](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en) about shutdown.

Still you can add schema to increase CTR.

Comment: What does, "Still you can add schema to increase CTR." mean?